# No graphics after installing Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I installed nvidia driver, rebooted, and got no graphics, only console.

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: More information please. At least your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Did you get any error messages on boot?

Comment: Duplicate question ... see  http://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide the version which comes up as installed when you run this command:

```
# dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

From the console you can use the following command to install (and I guess replace or remove) the binary driver installed:

```
# jockey-text
```

Keep in mind that you may just need to (re)move your xorg.conf (video server config file):

```
# mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old-darkness
```

Hope this helps.