# Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver

Tags: nvidia

I've [installed the current nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers) and rebooted my machine and now I get a black or blank screen.

How can I fix this?

Comment: (Those going for the bounty on this question, there's no need to redo all the optimus options, just add those existing answers as links in an all encompassing answer, cross-link as much as you can!)

Comment: A lot of the answers will fail using "sudo apt-get install nvidia-common" because of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-common/+bug/981874

Comment: could be an issue with the kernel version... Install ukuu and install a newer version of kernel. You can always revert back to the one you are using though.

Answer (score 80):

### Remove all Nvidia-related packages

1. Log in to a terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (terminal is visible with a blank screen)
2. `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`

### Start from scratch

1. `sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nv`

### Reinstall everything

1. `sudo apt-get install nvidia-common`
2. `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`
3. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core`

### Reconfigure the X server

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

*Source: [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection?action=show&redirect=X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem:__Need_to_fully_remove_-nvidia_and_reinstall_-nouveau_from_scratch)*

Comment: Finally, that fixed it (omitted "Start from scratch" stage - didn't fancy uninstalling xserver!) but did all the other steps and it works a treat. Many thanks!

Comment: That wiki is outdated. the nvidia-settings --uninstall doesn't work, for example.

Comment: @NoBugs: yes, but following the steps still fixes the graphics on 14.04 after `reboot`

Comment: Thank you.  I had to use `nvidia-common nvidia-current` anywhere you used `nvidia-common`, but it works.

Comment: When I run sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau I get the following message:  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau : Depends: xorg-video-abi-15
                              Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
                              Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 9.0)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. "           Any idea what to do in this case?

Comment: No longer working as of April 2016. None of the commands after `sudo apt-get install nvidia-common` work. This is on Ubuntu 14.04 on an Asus G751JM (nvidia GTX 860m)

Comment: Thanks for the steps. It also helped me. I needed the nvidia, although not all of those steps worked for me.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, removing nvidia proprietary drivers does not make them work...

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. Running Ubuntu 16.10 on my Thinkpad P50, still get the blinking cursor of death after reboot.

Comment: Worked for me (apart from nonexistant xserver-xorg-video-nv) with Ubuntu 16.10 on Dec 2016.

Comment: What if I'm specifically trying to install the nvidia drivers, not the noveau version?

Comment: I only did step 1 and it solved it to me....

Comment: This answer is outdated. It seems like a way to install the correct current `nvidia drivers` is by exectuing `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` after purging nvidia.

Comment: Black screen after reboot when following these steps.

Comment: It worked for me with Ubuntu 22.04. My issue was a black screen with only the _ at the most top left. Before the reboot, the OS freezed after installed the video drivers downloaded by the OS while installing it.

Answer (score 10):

1. Remove any drivers that may be causing the issue,
2. open the terminal and type ( open it from the dash, using the ubuntu icon on the left corner)

   ```
    sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia
   ```

   or

   ```
    sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current
   ```

   (Depending on which one you have installed) or deactivate them from the restricted driver settings.
3. reboot.
4. then on a terminal type this:

   ```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
   ```
5. reboot.

Comment: This worked for me, but left me with 640x480 equivalent problem to http://askubuntu.com/questions/201123/screen-resolution-stuck-at-640x480-after-installing-bumblebee. Also, use Shift/Esc during boot to enter linux equivalent of 'safe mode' so that you can execute these commands

Comment: Damn rep won't let me edit my own comment - just wanted to add that the solution proposed for the 640x480 problem in the question referenced above works fine, so don't let that hold you back.

Comment: If my computer starts up with a blank screen, how can I open a terminal to type those commands? The screen is blank!

Comment: @StefanLasiewski http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it?lq=1

Comment: The info here really should be added to Marco Scannadinari's answer above to improve/expand on already existing answer

Comment: @geezanansa Well considering my answer is around 1 year older than his...

Comment: Fix does not work for Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was a problem with the monitor giving my Nvidia GPU a bad EDID

To debug your error, you can add this line to the screen section in the the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file

```
Option         "ModeDebug" "true"
```

Now check your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log file`.

If you find an error like this:

```
NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device DFP-0's EDID; cannot compute DPI
```

Then you can resolve it by adding this line to the device section

```
Option         "IgnoreEDIDChecksum" "DFP"
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe Ubuntu IT'S working but using another card output. For me, my nVidia GeForce 7300 has 2 output, a VGA and a DVI. It seems like the default output when you install the drivers is to DVI but I don't have a DVI monitor so I managed to get to Recovery Mode (available in GRUB when you boot) and type this:

```
nvidia-xconfig --twinview --twinview-orientation="Clone"
```

Now Reboot.

This command directs the same graphics to both outputs. From there on, you can keep experimenting with this nVidia utility until you get what you want. For more information type:

```
nvidia-xconfig -A | less
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Press Alt+Ctrl+F1 to get to tty1 (terminal), then run this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia*
```

That will remove any nvidia driver packages. If that still doesn't work, try this also:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.mybak
```

That will remove a corrupted xorg configuration file if it exists. You will need to reboot after finishing these commands. (Ctrl+Alt+del)

PS. If you have an nvidia optimus card, do not install the x-swat or any other nvidia drivers. The best working drivers for nvidia optimus cards come from [the bumblebee project](http://bumblebee-project.org/).

Comment: Is the purpose of this to just default back to the nouveau driver ?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when running an AMD cpu: Learned it was an IOMMU/AMD -v Bug = Incompatible with Nvidia. Disabling Virtualization bios settings fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

Does [that thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744248) on Ubuntu Forums help you?

In short, it seems that the linux-header packages for some of the kernels (notably the PAE kernels) are not properly installed, and the nvidia driver compilation fails silently when installing the nvidia packages.

Comment: Thx for your post. But see edit 5! What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the topic title: What is the current restricted nvidia driver version used in Ubuntu natty?

You can find anything about releases, versions, bugs, requested features on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net). To understand what it is about you can take [their tour](https://launchpad.net/+tour/index).

The question about the latest version of the nVidia driver can be found on [“nvidia-current” binary package in Ubuntu Natty i386](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/i386/nvidia-current). So as of 2011-04-20 the latest version  is 270.41.06-0ubuntu1. But that is not necessarily the **recommended** one. The latest one for me always seems buggy (like 'tearing' etc).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using nvidia-current you should really try to use an older nvidia driver e.g. the 173.xx. This solved the problem for me. Just start jockey-gtk and chose the 173.xx driver. Than reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_GFXMODE=1680x1050x32
```

Replace "1680x1050x32| with your native resolution (to get it run `vbeinfo` in the grub console when booting).

Then in `/etc/grub.d/00_header`:

```
set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE} <-- FIND THIS LINE
set gfxpayload=keep <-- ADD THIS LINE DIRECTLY BENEATH
```

Update grub:

sudo update-grub

Might work...

Comment: Can you explain what some of these options do? What does `gfxpayload` do, for example?

Comment: Documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/gfxpayload.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `acpi=off`. That solved my booting into blank screen issue for Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: The original question was an old one.  The reason this probably wasn't suggested at the time is that the problem occurred only after the proprietary driver was installed.  A better answer might be to revert to the last known working driver, then try alternate nvidia drivers that have become available.

Comment: Where should `acpi=off` be set?

Comment: @Magick at the grub menu entry at boot time (press e to access). Then look for the line which passes options to the kernel  (starts with "linux"). See con-f-use answer below : https://askubuntu.com/a/43691/550380, this is will make the option permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I got a blank screen as well, but this was on a laptop with and nVidia optimus card 4200m. 
Optimus does not seem to be supported well on Ubuntu. I had to disable optimus from the bios and then reinstall the nividia driver. More here if you want to read http://developerslog.org/?p=69

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a black screen when booting.  I have a NVIDIA 6200 graphics card.  Renaming xorg.config and rebooting worked for me.  The xorg.config file created by nvidia-xconfig:  version 304.51  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06.nvidia.com) was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest trouble I had was getting a Macbook Pro to install the Nvidia drivers!!!

The solution is to change the Master Boot Partition to REMOVE EFI and go with Legacy MBP.

This is discussed on a few webpages but is not so easy to follow.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162289

Using this idea, I booted from a Live CD and then using Gparted removed the EFI boot partition, changed it from EFI to FAT32 and then using Boot-Repair rebuilt it as a legacy boot using the main Partition with 13.04 64 bit installed

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

---WARNING BACK UP YOUR DATA FIRST.  YOU COULD SCREW UP EVERYTHING ON YOUR HDD ---

Insert Live CD - Boot up as try Ubuntu
Run Gparted - Change EFI boot partition from EFI to FAT32.

open a new Terminal, then type:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

- Press Enter.
- Then type:

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)

In boot repair select ADVANCED OPTIONS

Uncheck Use the Standard EFI File under main options
Uncheck Separate /boot/efi partition under GRUB LOCATION

follow prompts on how to use the legacy Boot loader that Boot Repair will give you.

Now install and load the NVidia drivers as many post

I used the method 2 on this page  http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-ringtail-nvidia.html

I was working on this for probably 18 hours and tried EVERY option available.  I mean every possibly way to install these friggin drivers, and this was the only solution that works for the Macbook Pro 7.1 Running 13.04 with Nvidia_current (nvidia_304)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything here and the solution for me was to switch to lightdm, works perfectly now!

Comment: How do you switch to lightdm?