# Cannot upgrade or install 12.04 - Black screen

Tags: installation, 12.04, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver)

An update from 11.10 to 12.04 failed because of a boot into black screen (Nvidia graphics card) after selecting normal boot in Grub (recovery console was available though).

I then wiped the whole partition (deleting all proprietary drivers) and tried a fresh install, but could not run the installation cd because it was booting straight into a black screen again.

Now I reinstalled 11.10 (and installed proprietary Nvidia driver version 173), and would like to ask 2 questions:

1 - Is there a proven method to fix this problem from the recovery console, so that I can safely try upgrading again (without much knowledge of Ubuntu)?

2 - Is there a website which I could check for updated Nvidia drivers packaged into the upgrade, so that I can safely upgrade without running into a black screen some time later on?

Comment: I had this problem too; not sure if my findings may help:http://askubuntu.com/questions/125587/12-04-upgrade-causes-black-screen-of-death