# Blank screen upon boot after installing nvidia drivers. 12.10

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I tried to install nvidia Drivers on my most recent install of 12.10.  Now it no longer boots to the shell. It will only display a blank screen with the cursor flashing, but you will be unable to type.

The video card is a Gforce 9800 GT

Is there anyway to revert to the original display drivers? Or is the a way to fix the Nvidia drivers?  Or is my only option to try and re-install the OS?

I admit I'm new to this.

I have tried everything from [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver/41686#41686) and nothing fixes it, it still boots to a blank screen.

Comment: what grphics card do you have? is it optimus card? How did you install it. Please edit your question and include result of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: I do not know what lspci | grep VGA is.   The video card is a Gforce 9800 GT.

Comment: It came after I already completed the install. It worked with whatever generic drivers it used for the install. It was only after installing the nvidia drivers did it stop displaying anything.  I'm not sure if that is the same issue.

Comment: Try using `xswat` ppas for updated and stable driver as told here - http://askubuntu.com/a/41686/35775 .. It is same link as posted in above link to solve issues that is are caused by update. If that doesn't help, please post the result as I said before.