# No Unity desktop after last kernel update

Tags: 12.04, unity, kernel

I was using Ubuntu 12.04 perfectly on my desktop until last kernel update (3.2.0-51). After the update process and reboot of the system, the Unity interface didn't start. The only way to login in the system is by tty.  I have tried the last kernel versions available in the computer, but I can't use the graphical interface.

Until the text terminals is impossible to access the unity interface.

If I don't find a solution I will re-install the whole system.

Comment: Grub Menu > Advanced Options > choose an old kernel > boot to your desktop > `sudo apt-get install -f ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` > Restart

Comment: Thanks, but I don`t want upgrade my ubuntu version. I only use LTS versions, and in the old versions of kernel I can`t access my desktop. After enter my password the system backs to the login screen. Its possible to use the guest account, but my account seem blocked.

Comment: The link below solved my problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver It was a graphic driver problem.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` won't upgrade the Ubuntu version. To upgrade your version you should enter this command: `do-release-upgrade`. `dist-upgrade` will upgrade your kernel. Howeve, glad you solved your problem.