# Latest Ubuntu 12.04 kernel 3.2.0-51 does not boot graphical

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel

I can run it in safe mode and get the root prompt, but if I let it boot normally I just get a black screen.  A similar question was asked here:

[No Unity desktop after last kernel update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327894/pc-does-not-restart-after-last-kernel-update)

but I don't have a Nvidia graphics card. I am able to boot 3.2.0-43 just fine.

I did find this error in the kernel.log after trying to boot 3.2.0-51:

```
Aug 11 12:03:26 iceman kernel: [2.672181] [drm] MTRR allocation failed.  Graphics performance may suffer.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot to your root prompt.
2. # lspci -vvk >> ~/devices.txt
3. Post the devices.txt file here.
4. [Build your own kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) making sure to use menuconfig for your arch.

Be sure to enable MTRR for your system and possibly your VGA adapter.  Look for this option in menuconfig:

```
Processor type and features  --->
[*] MTRR (Memory Type Range Register) support
 [*]   MTRR cleanup support 
 (1)     MTRR cleanup enable value (0-1)
 (1)     MTRR cleanup spare reg num (0-7)
[*]   x86 PAT support
```

If those options are enabled, you need to enable the kernel command line options for your vga device.  See [Here](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/Framebuffer#ypan.2C_ywrap_and_redraw).  Yes, the Distro is different, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the the response E Carter Young, but later kernels fixed my issue and I no longer have the setup to test any further.