# 13.04 doesn't boot after installing nvidia driver 319.49

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

So I install this new driver because I wanted access to cuda.

Now, the only thing my computer does when booting is going to a black screen with an underscore flashing on the top-left corner. Before that point, I see rapidly the tty login screen but I don't have time to log there.

Any ideas what I should do about that?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver)

Answer (score 1):

Following @TrailRider link, I managed to solve this problem. Not sure exactly what did the thing, but I solved it.

1) be sure to purge any nvidia-current package!
2) if you install with the nVidia driver, run it like:

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.49.run --uninstall
```

So that it will clear any bad things that was there
3) finally, just reinstall normally:

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.49.run
```

Now, I have access to cuda again. Thanks to everyone that took time to read this question and a special thanks to @TrailRider!

Answer (score 0):

First remove all nvidia packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then reinstall the current nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

You can install the CUDA toolkit using:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-cuda-toolkit