# Nvidia driver - After install - No unity or black screen with cursor

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 x64, I've tried many distros based on Ubuntu/Debian as well.
For example: Mint 13,14,15 KDE & Cinnamon, Kubuntu, Xubuntu etc.

My graphic cards: - Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (DEFAULT)
                  - NVIDIA GeForce GT635M 2GB (Need to be installed correctly)

I was looking on the internet to find the sulotion, but nothing.
Then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

After reboot, Unity dissappered or black screen with cursor.
I've also tried to look into "Driver Manager" but there was nothing to install..

Someone knows the solution?
How to install my Nvidia Driver correctly and make it working.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver
http://askubuntu.com/questions/372686/after-installing-nvidia-drivers-i-boot-into-a-black-screen-13-10
http://askubuntu.com/questions/417426/ubuntu-13-10-black-screen-after-installing-nvidia-optimus-drivers

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you remove the nvidia drivers, and then install bumblebee, since you got optimus:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

After that, reboot and hope it works.