# black screen, blinking if Alt+Ctrl+F1

Tags: 12.04

**Problem and what I've done:**

I'm having tons of trouble getting Ubuntu to boot after installation. The Grub menu works fine and I can boot into windows without problems.

Booting into Ubuntu however not so successful. I've tried various fixes, some of them I can't remember but two from this site I do remember are:

- [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)
- [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver) (This step is what got me into the broken GUI)
- I've tried kernal upgrades/downgrades
- I've tried multiple different Nvidia drivers
- I've tried adding "nomodeset" (This allows me to at least get into the console, but not always)
- Tried "noapic" and "nolapic" to no avail (this makes it worse in some cases)
- running startx from the console, when I manage to make it that far, gives errors saying it's already running.
- Every boot up has the agpgart module failed to initialize error (I
  ve also tried 2 fixes for this which didn't do much. With one I still got the error.)

I've tried various methods of installing/updating/replacing and removing Nvidia drivers. The best I've done is get into Ubuntu with massive black borders (not filling my screen or seeing second screen). In fact Ubuntu thought it was a laptop screen. Also "additional drivers" does nothing, just loops it's little loading bar thingy.  <--- for those who missed it, this is the broken GUI scenario :D

Some of the fixes allow me to at least access the terminal to login and use commands, and with that I managed to try things up until I got into the broken GUI mentioned above.

I've first tried installing with my own partitioning:

- "/swap" 8GB
- "/" Rest of space

With that installation I tried all the fixes and managed to get to my broken GUI. After that I decided to re-install, this time picking the "alongside" option, however it has the exact same problem.

**The current situation and problem:**

I select Ubuntu in Grub (Windows still boots fine). It briefly displays a blinking cursor, then fades to black. As if the computer is going into sleep. If I then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I get the blinking cursor with nothing to do but turn off the machine via the power button. I'm assuming adding "nomodeset" will get me into the terminal like it did before.

Here is a link to information of my system: [A link of average specs and some basic info](http://pastebin.com/BnP93bYq)

This is just too keep the question relatively clean for anyone not interested in the nitty gritty. If there is another question that lead along these lines I apologize, in that case google has betrayed me and we'll have to discuss where our relationship is headed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I've linked that in my question, none of those fixed my problem. I've already gone through that and tried the fixes there.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question as the proposed duplicate does not fix this users problem.

Comment: Would it make any difference if I made a "/boot" mount while installing?