# How to install grphics card driver installation on dell inspiron N5010

Tags: drivers

I am not able to install graphic card drivers on my Dell Inspiron N5010 model laptop. When I am trying to install fglrx from terminal

```
vijay@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install fglrx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Conflicts: xorg-driver-binary
 nvidia-304-updates : Conflicts: xorg-driver-binary
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an Nvidia card ?    here is a set of commands I've used to good effect :

[Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/q/41681/18025)