# HDMI connection between TV and a laptop with Ubuntu (14.04) + NVIDIA Optimus possible?

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, nvidia-optimus, tv

### Question briefly:

Is it possible to connect a Ubuntu laptop with NVIDIA Optimus to a TV via HDMI connection? The connection should also have sounds included, because otherwise it would be easier just to go with a VGA cable.

### Background information:

I have been trying to connect my ASUS U31JG with NVIDIA Optimus GeForce GT 415M CUDA GPU to my Samsung TV via a HDMI cable. This causes the laptop screen to "crash" (it divides to two 'halfs', and stops responding). However, Ctrl+Alt+F1 still opens new terminal window succesfully, so it looks like that only the screen crashes, not the whole PC.

I have  `nvidia-common`, `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`, `libgl1-mesa-glx`, `libgl1-mesa-dri` and `xserver-xorg-core` installed (a 'fresh' installation of them all).

and my `lspci -nn | grep VGA` output is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 18)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 415M] [10de:0dee] (rev a1)
```

**Edit:**

The additional drivers I am using are (from: 'additional drivers')

```
Nvidia Corporation: GF108M [GeForce GT 415M]
* Using X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)
```

Comment: Can you tell me what graphics driver you are using? Are you running the open source nouveau or the latest NVIDIA?

Comment: I have basically followed these steps: http://askubuntu.com/a/163808/215022. How can I be sure which driver is in use?

Comment: if you open 'additional drivers' it should say.