# Ubuntu 14.04LTS Black Screen (Already purged NVIDIA)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

**What's happening:**
Black screen instead of desktop. I see the purple screen with the Ubuntu logo before it goes to black. My monitors are plugged into my motherboard (just like they were before I purged NVIDIA). I can also open terminal through CTRL+ALT+T.

**What I've done:**
I was getting some weird errors and screen tearing, so in an attempt to just have my integrated graphics I did this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nv
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

But that does nothing still. (I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver) by the way)

I also tried copying my backed up "xorg.conf", but that has no effect. I have gone through the Xorg log, but it shows no errors. I don't know how to post it, because I have no browser access on Ubuntu.

I have started and restarted lightdm, but it doesn't do anything either.

I booted into the failsafe graphics mode (or w/e it's called), and when it gives me an option to reconfigure it doesn't actually do anything -- just sends me back through the menus. At the beginning it says that the configuration couldn't be loaded, or couldn't be found, and that it needs to be reconfigured.

My best guess is that I ruined the OpenGL drivers, but I don't know how to fix it. Help? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild your kernel image:

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Sometimes it usefull.

Is there also old kernel on your installation to boot? Please try to boot with old kernel version and image.