# Why recommended driver is different from the latest supported driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I was going step by step reading this tutorial:
http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/
but after I installed nvidia-current and open the Kubuntu Driver Manager , the recomMended version to install is 340. But in the nvidia site I found 346 as the right one.

```
krasen@krasen-Lenovo-Y50-70:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nvidia-304 nvidia-opencl-icd-304 nvidia-settings
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-304 nvidia-current nvidia-opencl-icd-304 nvidia-settings
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 40,9 MB/41,9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 194 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ utopic/main nvidia-304 amd64 304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1 [35,5 MB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ utopic/main nvidia-current amd64 304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1 [8188 B]           
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ utopic/main nvidia-opencl-icd-304 amd64 304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1 [5412 kB]   
Fetched 40,9 MB in 13s (2957 kB/s)                                                                                                         
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-304.
(Reading database ... 184306 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-304_304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-304 (304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-current.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-current_304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-current (304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-opencl-icd-304.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-opencl-icd-304_304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-opencl-icd-304 (304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-settings.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-settings_346.35-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-settings (346.35-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.55ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up nvidia-304 (304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-304/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-304/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/nvidia-304/glamor.conf to provide /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/glamoregl.conf (glamor_conf) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-304
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Loading new nvidia-304-304.125 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.16.0-30-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.16.0-30-generic
Done.

nvidia_304:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up nvidia-current (304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-opencl-icd-304 (304.125-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1) ...
Setting up nvidia-settings (346.35-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.10.1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-10ubuntu2.2) ...
krasen@krasen-Lenovo-Y50-70:~$
```

At the end there is "Setting up nvidia-settings (346.35..." so this is the driver that is set up and ready to run. When refreshing Kubuntu Driver Manager there is still 340 and nouveau.

Furthermore running glxinfo is giving me error. I tried this hole procedure so many times. Purging all nvidia drivers then installing via the repository or directly downloading the nvidia driver. Always something went wrong. I'm not sure even if restart my PC again will it work or not. Once the x is not starting , or the had resolution about 600 x 600 (when trying to install the drivers from the nvidia site and running nvidia-xconfig). Why is it so hard. 
So after the code above here is the output from glxgears:

```
krasen@krasen-Lenovo-Y50-70:~$ glxgears 
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  23
  Current serial number in output stream:  24
```

After restarting I had black sreen with only one message that blinked three times:

```
failed toapply acl on /dev/dri/card1 no such file or direcory
```

In the moment of this message the Xorg.0.log looks like this:

```
[    50.633] 
X.Org X Server 1.16.1.901 (1.16.2 RC 1)
Release Date: 2014-11-02
[    50.633] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    50.633] Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-39-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    50.633] Current Operating System: Linux krasen-Lenovo-Y50-70 3.16.0-30-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 12 22:06:37 UTC 2015 x86_64
[    50.633] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic root=UUID=a7771c83-13b4-473b-b31e-1e62289256e2 ro quiet splash ipv6.disable=1
[    50.633] Build Date: 20 November 2014  09:55:19PM
[    50.633] xorg-server 2:1.16.1.901-1ubuntu1~utopic1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    50.633] Current version of pixman: 0.32.4
[    50.633]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    50.633] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    50.633] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 31 09:44:09 2015
[    50.633] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    50.633] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    50.634] (==) ServerLayout "layout"
[    50.634] (**) |-->Screen "nvidia" (0)
[    50.634] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    50.634] (**) |   |-->Device "nvidia"
[    50.634] (==) No monitor specified for screen "nvidia".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    50.634] (**) |-->Inactive Device "intel"
[    50.634] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    50.634] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    50.634] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    50.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    50.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    50.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    50.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    50.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    50.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    50.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    50.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    50.634] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    50.634]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    50.634] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    50.634] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    50.634] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    50.634] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f2e2a1dbd80
[    50.634] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    50.634]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    50.634]    X.Org Video Driver: 18.0
[    50.634]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[    50.634]    X.Org Server Extension : 8.0
[    50.634] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    50.635] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:17aa:3978 rev 6, Mem @ 0xd1000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64
[    50.635] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:1392:17aa:3978 rev 162, Mem @ 0xd0000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xb0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    50.635] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    50.635] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    50.635] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[    50.635] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    50.635] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    50.640] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    50.640]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    50.640]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    50.640] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.125  Mon Dec  1 20:22:48 PST 2014
[    50.640] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    50.640] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    50.640] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    50.640]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    50.640]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    50.664] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[    50.664] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.
[    50.664] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    50.664] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    50.665] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)
[    50.665] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    50.665] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    50.665] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    50.665]    compiled for 1.16.1.901, module version = 2.99.917
[    50.665]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    50.665]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    50.665] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    50.665] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[    50.665] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    50.665] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    50.665] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    50.665] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    50.665] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    50.665] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    50.665] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    50.665]    compiled for 1.16.1.901, module version = 2.99.917
[    50.665]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    50.665]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    50.665] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
[    50.665] (II) Unloading intel
[    50.665] (II) Failed to load module "intel" (already loaded, 32558)
[    50.665] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    50.665] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    50.665] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    50.665]    compiled for 1.16.0, module version = 0.9.0
[    50.665]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    50.665]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    50.665] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    50.665] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    50.665] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    50.665]    compiled for 1.16.0, module version = 0.4.4
[    50.665]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    50.665]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    50.665] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    50.666] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    50.666] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    50.666]    compiled for 1.16.0, module version = 2.3.3
[    50.666]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    50.666]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    50.666] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    50.666] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[    50.666] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[    50.666] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[    50.666] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    50.666] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    50.666] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    50.666] (++) using VT number 7

[    50.666] (II) intel(G0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20080730
[    50.666] (II) intel(G0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20150129.58fe4089-0ubuntu0sarvatt~utopic (Robert Hooker <sarvatt@ubuntu.com>)
[    50.666] (II) intel(G0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    50.666] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    50.666] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    50.666] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    50.666] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    50.666] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    50.666] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    50.666]    compiled for 1.16.1.901, module version = 0.0.2
[    50.666]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 18.0
[    50.666] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    50.666] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    50.666] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    50.666] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[    50.666] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    50.666] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    50.666] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    50.666] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    50.666] (EE) 
[    50.669] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

and xorg.conf :

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "SNA"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

I didn't know how to resolve this problem so I did again:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and managed to get to the desktop

Comment: Similar issue for "recommended driver" being indicated on 14.10 with 6800 gt with 304.125 driver. Givesblack screen even with nomodeset.   init messages indicate broken pipe early in boot process.   This needs an answer.

Comment: The answer here needs improve/expanded on. http://askubuntu.com/a/163808 imo it does not fully answer the question.  User is asking how to fix proprietary driver install and not only revert back to open source driver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already installed the xorg-edgers PPA, when you execute the following command:

```
apt-cache search nvidia | grep --ignore-case binary | grep version
```

you should receive:

```
nvidia-304 - NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.125
nvidia-331 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.113
nvidia-340 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.76
nvidia-346 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 346.35
nvidia-352 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.30
nvidia-355 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 355.06
```

To install the latest driver, perform the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355.06
```

(do not use nvidia-current!) and reboot and test

If that doesn't solve your problem, go back one level (340) and if that doesn't work another one and another one until it works.  If none work, disable the NVidia chip in your BIOS wait a few weeks and try again with the latest driver (there currently are a bit of problems with NVidia)

Comment: I tryed this. Install, restart, black screen, install lower version,  restart, black screen, install lower versiom...and so on. At the en I purged nvidia* and restated. The thing is that before I had installed nvidia drivers on this machine but don't remember how. It was on linux mint and it was via repository

Comment: The 343 driver was deleted from the repository recently as it caused too much problems (but unfortunately also solved some unique issues.)  Disable your NVidia in the mean time and wait for a couple of weeks: there is e new version in the pipeline.  I've marked your question as a favourite, so the moment I see it coming in, I'll come back and give you an update!  ;-)

Comment: I found a [repository with the 343 driver](http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin/pool/universe/n/nvidia-graphics-drivers-343/) for you!  (beware: use at your own risk, a [system back-up](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) is advisable before you start.  You've been promoted to user type 4.)

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to wipe everything related with nvidia, to remove all repositories like ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa that I added additionally , and to download and install the nvidia drivers from nvidia site. Is not exact answer of my question , but be free to down vote if you want.