# Can't log in after installing CUDA

Tags: nvidia, 14.10, cuda

Ubuntu 14.10, CUDA 7, installed throught deb repository and then `sudo apt-get install cuda`.

I have the Nvidia 349 drivers.

After reboot I'm stuck on a screen with written **Ubuntu 14.10** and four points (three white, the last orange) on a black bar. If I press the shutdown button (once) it will shutdown after a few seconds.

I've seen this thread [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver) but

1. I don't have problems with the drivers themselves, only after installing cuda.
2. I do not know how to open a console from that black screen.

Answer (score 0):

To get a console press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> at the broken login screen. If that does not work boot into recover mode, drop to a root prompt, remount the root directory :

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Once logged in try uninstalling cuda :

```
sudo apt-get remove cuda
```

or the driver

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-349
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-346
```

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck at this login screen due to issue of Nvidia driver at startup.
Try change to Intel at shutdown at set to Nvidia at startup.

1. create `select_intel.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   echo <your ubuntu password> | sudo -S prime-select intel
   ```
2. `sudo +x select_intel.sh`
3. `sudo mv select_intel.sh /etc/init.d/`
4. `sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/select_intel.sh /etc/rc0.d/K99select_intel`
5. `sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/select_intel.sh /etc/rc6.d/K99select_intel`

For startup

1. `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
2. add this code above `exit 0`

   ```
   echo <your ubuntu password> | sudo -S prime-select nvidia
   ```

Note that  is your ubuntu password for sudo command.
This is just a workaround, not a solution, but it works.