# Not able to boot from CD/USB after intel_config_compare error Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, fsck

**I have tried re-installing ubuntu desktop. It isn't helping.**

I was transferring heavy files from file system to hard drive and suspended it for a while as the computer slowed down. I was not able to wake the system from suspension and so did a forced shut-down. When i booted it up again, it asked me to run fsck manually. I did that and after I got the message 'File system was modified' I typed exit in the terminal. Then instead of starting up, ubuntu got stuck  in the start up screen and didn't proceed further. The error it shows is:

```
    intel_pipe_config_compare [i915] *ERROR* mismatch in ips_enabled (expected 1, found 0)
```

tty 4 is working but without internet. tty 7 has this error. If i try booting ubuntu 15.10 from usb, its not getting recognised. Even windows installation CD isn't working. How do I get my ubuntu desktop without losing data?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue (also in 15.10).  I also remember having to do a hard shutdown (ie just holding the power button down until it turns off).  In startup I get as far as: 
'code'Starting Daemon for power management...
'code'[ OK ] Started daemon for power management.

I have wifi and internet, and have tried running through the top two answers from this question, as I suspect my nvidia drivers may be involved (but have had no luck).  
http://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver