# How to boot to a terminal from a black screen and flashing cursor after updating the NVIDA graphics driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, lightdm

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and updated my graphics card to Nvidia Quadro K4200 in order to get stereo capability. It worked with the recommended Ubuntu driver (nvidia-352), although I struggled to get stereo working, so I installed the latest Nvidia driver (361.42).  To do this, I got a terminal with

> `Alt-Ctrl-F1`

stopped X with

> `sudo service lightdm stop`

and then ran the install script from NVIDIA.  When I restarted X with

> `sudo service lightdm start`

I got a black screen with a blinking cursor in the top left of the screen and Alt-Ctrl-F[1-6] did not give a terminal login.  My only option is a hard shutdown (holding down the start button) and when I reboot it returns to the black screen.

I saw [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver?lq=1) which looks the closest to my problem that I found, with a solution that requires Alt-Ctrl-F1 which isn't giving me a terminal login option. Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:  For low level logins, like you're doing, frequently the ENTER key must be pressed to get a login prompt.

Just because the graphics are crazy, doesn't mean that the daemons like sshd didn't come up properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with NVIDIA install script. I've booted into recovery mode (hold SHIFT before loading GRUB for a menu) and there was an option to open a root terminal.

Try those commands, reboot and see if it will fix your case:

> dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
>
> update-initramfs -u

You might need to remount with write priviledges to make those changes:

> mount -o remount,rw /

With terminal you can of course remove NVIDIA and re-install `nouveau-firmware`, just run that `update-initramfs -u` afterwards. I think I fixed it just like that, but it was some time ago and my memory is foggy...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed on desperate rebooting I intermittently got a login prompt, sometimes giving my a couple of minutes of access before returning to the black screen and flashing cursor.  I found in /var/log/kern.log the following error:

> NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 361.42, but
>
> NVRM: this kernel module has the version 352.63.  Please
>
> NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
>
> NVRM: components have the same version
>
> NVRM: nvidia_frontend_ioctl: minor 255, module->ioctl fauled, error
>   -22

I ran

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
```

for a list of nvidia packages that might be causing the conflict and removed and purged all of them individually

```
apt-get remove *package*

apt-get purge *package*
```

I also re-ran the NVIDIA driver install script to generate a customised kernel setup for good measure and re-ran the install.

This got me to the login screen on reboot, although logging in kept returning me to the login screen, but I could at least ctrl-alt-F1 for a terminal and there was plenty of help on this issue already on Ask.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for errors?

Or when you stop X, try `startx` rather than restarting the service.

Comment: He can't really run a command when he has no access to a terminal...

Comment: Hi Byte Commander, at the end they say they can, alternatively, if they start their machine immediately hold the shift key down, will provide recovery mode