# Ubuntu 14.04 stuck at boot splash screen

Tags: nvidia-geforce

This hapenned for me after trying to install tvtime, and i don't know the probleme where exactly, i think because my Nvidia card not probaply well installed.
i tryed to boot with older kernels but the problem is not resolved.
any help please ...

---

now the splash screen have a black strip with small vibration and Ubuntu is blocked in this screen.

Comment: Did you use apt-get to install the nvidia drivers?

Comment: i forget how i installed nvidia, but now when i login by Crtl + Alt + F2 and i type in terminal : nvidia-detector, the output is : none

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver)

Comment: @DavidFoerster when i tryed to install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau, i have  problem with libcheese-gtk23 and libcheese7

Comment: That problem can be solved. Please [open a new question](/questions/ask) for it though as the comment section is not the right place for follow-up questions or extended discussion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tty work correctly but GUI does not work in Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/773165/tty-work-correctly-but-gui-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Duplicate of this question.

Comment: What is your specific nvidia type or model?

Comment: @loulid39 I don't know. Consider reinstalling. I really hate to say that but it looks like this is just way too beyond the scope here. We gave it a good try. If you are feeling adventurous and if it doesn't matter if you mess things up even further, you could try commenting out line 86 in /usr/bin/click and try uninstalling again.

Answer (score 0):

Use nano to edit your sources.list file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to delete all the lines in the file.

Next, place the following lines in the file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to save the file, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Reboot.

Please post any errors.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40023/discussion-on-answer-by-mchid-ubuntu-14-04-stuck-at-boot-splash-screen).