# GUI not starting in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nvidia, 17.10

I just upgraded my laptop to 17.10. Upgrade went fine but when booting up, the gui won't start. The screen flicker and I have to login to the terminal and stop gdm3. I've tried removing and reinstalling the NVIDIA driver, but same results. I see this in syslog:

```
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 128...
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gdm3: Child process -3487 was already dead.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Stopped target Default.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gdm3: Child process 3477 was already dead.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gdm3: Unable to kill session worker process
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Stopped target Basic System.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Stopped target Sockets.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Closed Sound System.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Stopped target Paths.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Stopped target Timers.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Reached target Shutdown.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Starting Exit the Session...
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3481]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 3539 (kill).
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 128.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of gdm.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of gdm.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 128...
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Started Session c19 of user gdm.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Reached target Timers.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Listening on Sound System.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Reached target Paths.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Reached target Sockets.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Reached target Basic System.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Reached target Default.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Startup finished in 19ms.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 128.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp dbus-daemon[3550]: Activating service name='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp org.gnome.ScreenSaver[3550]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gnome-screensav[3558]: Cannot open display: 
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp dbus-daemon[3550]: Activated service 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' failed: Process org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gnome-session[3552]: gnome-session-binary[3552]: CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.ScreenSaver: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gnome-session-binary[3552]: CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.ScreenSaver: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gnome-shell[3560]: Can't initialize KMS backend: could not find drm kms device
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gnome-session[3552]: gnome-session-binary[3552]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gnome-session-binary[3552]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gnome-session-binary[3552]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gdm3: GdmDisplay: display lasted 0.152136 seconds
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gdm3: Child process -3548 was already dead.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gdm3: Child process 3538 was already dead.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 128...
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp gdm3: Unable to kill session worker process
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Stopped target Default.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Stopped target Basic System.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Stopped target Paths.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Stopped target Timers.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Stopped target Sockets.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Closed Sound System.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Reached target Shutdown.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Starting Exit the Session...
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[3542]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 3568 (kill).
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 128.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of gdm.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of gdm.
Oct 20 11:50:28 torp systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 128...
```

Anybody know how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Hardware details:

Lenovo Y510P
Intel Core i7 2.40Ghz CPU
NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M video card

Further updates:

I am seeing this in syslog:

```
Oct 22 21:40:37 torp systemd[4036]: Starting Accessibility services bus...
Oct 22 21:40:37 torp dbus-daemon[4051]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
Oct 22 21:40:37 torp systemd[4036]: Started Accessibility services bus.
Oct 22 21:40:37 torp at-spi-bus-launcher[4060]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Oct 22 21:40:37 torp gnome-session[4058]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Oct 22 21:40:37 torp gnome-session[4058]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GL Helper exited with code 256
Oct 22 21:40:37 torp at-spi-bus-launcher[4060]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Oct 22 21:40:37 torp org.a11y.atspi.Registry[4065]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Oct 22 21:40:37 torp gnome-session-c[4069]: eglGetDisplay() failed
Oct 22 21:40:37 torp gnome-session[4058]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GLES Helper exited with code 256
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gnome-session[4058]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gnome-session[4058]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GL Helper exited with code 256
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gnome-session-c[4077]: eglGetDisplay() failed
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gnome-session[4058]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: GLES Helper exited with code 256
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gnome-session[4058]: gnome-session-binary[4058]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gnome-session[4058]: gnome-session-binary[4058]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gnome-session-binary[4058]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gnome-session-binary[4058]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp org.a11y.atspi.Registry[4065]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp org.a11y.atspi.Registry[4065]:       after 21 requests (21 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (**) Option "fd" "22"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) event3  - (II) Power Button: (II) device removed
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (**) Option "fd" "25"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) event0  - (II) Power Button: (II) device removed
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (**) Option "fd" "26"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) event1  - (II) Sleep Button: (II) device removed
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (**) Option "fd" "27"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) event5  - (II) Video Bus: (II) device removed
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (**) Option "fd" "28"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) event8  - (II) Lenovo EasyCamera: Lenovo EasyC: (II) device removed
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (**) Option "fd" "29"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) event7  - (II) Ideapad extra buttons: (II) device removed
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (**) Option "fd" "30"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) event4  - (II) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: (II) device removed
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:70
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:71
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:72
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:69
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4042]: (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 128...
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Stopped target Default.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gdm3: Child process -4042 was already dead.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gdm3: Child process 4032 was already dead.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gdm3: Unable to kill session worker process
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Stopped target Basic System.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Stopped target Paths.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Stopped target Sockets.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Closed Sound System.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Stopped target Timers.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Reached target Shutdown.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Starting Exit the Session...
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4036]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 4109 (kill).
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 128.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of gdm.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of gdm.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 128...
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[1]: Started Session c35 of user gdm.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4110]: Reached target Paths.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4110]: Reached target Timers.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4110]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4110]: Listening on Sound System.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4110]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4110]: Reached target Sockets.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4110]: Reached target Basic System.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4110]: Reached target Default.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4110]: Startup finished in 17ms.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 128.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp systemd[4110]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp dbus-daemon[4118]: Activating service name='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp org.gnome.ScreenSaver[4118]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Oct 22 21:40:42 torp gnome-screensav[4126]: Cannot open display:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Since I have an nvidia card, I had already tried:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics

and

https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver

with the same results.

Comment: I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Y510P with GeForce GT 755M so virtually the same. Never seen any real issue with a fresh install of 17.10 (other than some current gdm3 bugs with nvidia drivers in use, more the annoyance type). So I suggest you just copy out any files you want to save & do a fresh install.  If you do so keep in mind - When switching Gpu's a restart is always needed, log out/in does not work. Also when rebooting while on nvidia drivers the reboot or shutdown may hang. If so hit `ctrl+alt+F7`  & it will proceed

Comment: Just to note: If you want the best current ubuntu for this machine I'd just use 16.04.3 image with prime sync enabled. 17.10 is a bug ridden mess that is only suitable for finding & reporting these bugs in hopes that 18.04 is usable. 17.10 is Not suitable for main use Os.

Comment: It might not be exclusive to Nvidia. My PC booted fine with the beta 2, but the final won't start the GUI. I'm using the open source Radeon driver.

Maybe 17.10.1 will boot again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I felt foolish after having similar issues and finding the solution, but since my errors are similar to yours, down to the module not found message, I thought I'd share in case it helps:

After reinstalling the `nvidia-384` package for the third time, I noticed that it mentioned it was skipping building the modules for the new "low-latency" kernel because the headers couldn't be found. After following these steps, I was good to go:

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia-*'
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install nvidia-384
```

Note that I did prevent gdm from using Wayland prior to trying anything, and from what I understand Wayland won't currently work with the nvidia binaries, so I'd advise ensuring it's disabled in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` by uncommenting the line `#WaylandEnable=false`.

Comment: Agreed, I rushed through things at first and wasn't thinking.

Comment: Anyone trying this, I suggest you leave Wayland enabled. For me it was just the headers. Wayland had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Here is how I solved it.

1. I booted in the safe mode, selected TTY 4 (whatever) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, logged in and removed all nvidia drivers using `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia-*`. It switched to the login screen.
2. I entered the Gnome desktop. Then I added a repo with the latest drivers using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`.
3. Then I executed repo update `sudo apt update`.
4. I opened the Software & Updates > Additional Drivers and selected the newest driver (there were a few of them, and at the time of wtiting this text the newest was 387.12). The other versions just failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding nomodeset to your kernel cmdline. That's the last thing I did and now it works. It didn't work yesterday after doing that, and I'm unsure why it worked today, but it works now so I'll take it.

Comment: Just tried that, but nothing.

Comment: Ok, the other two things I did was uncomment #WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and blacklist the ast module for my onboard video (you probably don't have this video though).

If you run `modprobe nvidia` from a terminal what does it do?

Comment: This is what I am seeing:

`~$ sudo modprobe nvidia
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia_384'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_384': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)`

Answer (score 0):

My system also started but no GUI.

Try removing "quiet splash" from the kernel command line but keep "vt.handoff=7".

e.g.

BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-16-generic root=UUID=xxxxxxxxxxx ro vt.handoff=7

Comment: Thanks. I removed `quiet splash` from the command, but still no luck. Wondering if there is something wrong with the nvidia drivers? I've already reinstalled them as well.

Comment: Sorry it did not work out. About nvidia: you are running it in a VM so the Host VM's hardware is not important. The guest VM exposes it own virtual grahics card/interface.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and already opened up a bug report (Bug #1725169) in ubuntu xorg.
Maybe this was the wrong place because it gave only one reply yet.
The main problem is the unasked installation of the lowlatency-kernel. I might affect many others.