# nvidia drivers not working on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10

I have a problem since the last time I did `sudo apt dist-upgrade` in my ubuntu machone as the one described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968365/ubuntu-17-10-nvidia-drivers-black-screen-loop). However, none of their solutions worked, starting by the fact that I am not using the low latency kernel.

I follow all the steps that seem to work:

1. Blacklisting the `noveau` driver.
2. Setting `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub`.
3. Setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"` also in `/etc/default/grub` (2 and 3 were not set simultaneously).
4. Installing lightdm.
5. Reinstalling the nvidia drivers with `apt purge ^nvidia` and `apt install --reinstall nvidia-384`.

While (4) finally gave me a login screen, longing in in gnome didn't work.

`sudo journalctl -ocat` yields:

```
(II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
(II) LoadModule: "glx"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
(II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
        compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
        Module class: X.Org Server Extension
(II) NVIDIA GLX Module  384.90  Tue Sep 19 17:00:25 PDT 2017
(==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
(==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
(==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
(==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
(==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
(==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
(II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
(II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
        compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
        Module class: X.Org Video Driver
(II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
(II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.15
        Module class: X.Org Video Driver
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
(II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
(II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 1.19.5
        Module class: X.Org Video Driver
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
(II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
(II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
        Module class: X.Org Video Driver
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
(II) LoadModule: "vesa"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
(II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
        Module class: X.Org Video Driver
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
(II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  384.90  Tue Sep 19 16:35:54 PDT 2017
(II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
(II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Fri Apr 21 14:41:17 2017 -0400
(II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
        RIVA TNT        (NV04)
        RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
        GeForce 256     (NV10)
        GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
        GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
        GeForce 3       (NV20)
        GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
        GeForce FX      (NV3x)
        GeForce 6       (NV4x)
        GeForce 7       (G7x)
        GeForce 8       (G8x)
        GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
        GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
(II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
(II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
(II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) LoadModule: "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
(II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 1.0.0
        ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(II) Loading sub module "wfb"
(II) LoadModule: "wfb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
(II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 1.0.0
        ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
(II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
(II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
(EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
(EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
(EE) NVIDIA:     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
(EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
(EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
(EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
(II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
(II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
(II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 0.0.2
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
(**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 1@0:0:0
(II) FBDEV(1): using default device
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
(EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
(II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
(II) FBDEV(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
        "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
(==) FBDEV(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
(==) FBDEV(0): RGB weight 888
(==) FBDEV(0): Default visual is TrueColor
(==) FBDEV(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(II) FBDEV(0): hardware: EFI VGA (video memory: 3072kB)
(II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against framebuffer device...
(II) FBDEV(0): checking modes against monitor...
(--) FBDEV(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 1024)
(**) FBDEV(0):  Built-in mode "current": 78.7 MHz, 59.9 kHz, 75.7 Hz
(II) FBDEV(0): Modeline "current"x0.0   78.65  1024 1056 1184 1312  768 772 776 792 -hsync -vsync -csync (59.9 kHz b)
(==) FBDEV(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) LoadModule: "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
(II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 1.0.0
        ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(**) FBDEV(0): using shadow framebuffer
(II) Loading sub module "shadow"
(II) LoadModule: "shadow"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
(II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 1.1.0
        ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
(II) Unloading vesa
(==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
(II) FBDEV(0): FBIOBLANK: Invalid argument (Screen blanking not supported by kernel - disabling)
(==) FBDEV(0): Backing store enabled
(==) FBDEV(0): DPMS enabled
(==) RandR enabled
(II) SELinux: Disabled on system
(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D1: ca0132 DSP downloaded and running
```

I don't understand the messages related to the `noveau` driver since it is restricted.

`dmesg` yields:

```
[    1.279020] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    1.279024] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    1.279024] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    1.282601] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    1.282771] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[    1.352268] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[    3.301475] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[    3.363942] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[    5.009364] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[    5.035475] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   11.100897] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   11.166281] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   17.195212] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   17.234473] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   23.235776] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   23.284352] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   29.288938] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   29.333988] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   35.333656] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   35.369983] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   41.349484] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   41.399202] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   47.400332] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   47.447558] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   53.461137] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   53.497349] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   59.512240] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   59.562157] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   65.555357] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   65.589552] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   71.588204] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
[   71.639669] nvidia: Unknown symbol mcount (err 0)
```

That last message repeats another hundred times at least.

Removing completely the driver let's me use the computer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at [this thread](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/415) I realized that I had changed the default compiler `cc` from `gcc` to `clang` (same for `c++` from `g++` to `clang++`). So the fix:

1. Revert the default compiler to `gcc`.
2. Run `apt clean` to clean up the apt cache.
3. Reinstall the nvidia drivers.

Comment: Same here. That was a difficult error to spot. I had to reconfigure gcc as well, since update-alternatives completely failed to find it for some reason.