# Low-Latency Wayland Boot Issue

Tags: nvidia, 17.10

I am running [Ubuntu 17.10 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/1710) x64. I changed driver from XOrg to the NVidia Display Driver via additional drivers (not adding [PPAs](http://linuxbsdos.com/2017/06/11/how-to-install-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1070-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-10-17-04/)). After performing a reboot, I am able to load past Grub and am greeted with a blank pink screen.

I tried to edit Grub and replace `quiet splash` with `text`, and also performing some work via `tty2`. The issue is I cannot get to a shell besides the  `grub` recovery screen to perform any commands.

I want to try the solution on [Ubuntu 17.10 Nvidia Drivers, black screen loop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968365/ubuntu-17-10-nvidia-drivers-black-screen-loop) but I cannot get to `tty` to perform anything, and as soon as I load into recovery, I lose Keyboard and Mouse input.

Might be benefitial to confirm how to get to `tty`. I believe `alt` + `f2` no longer works, but `f3` to `f7` should.

Comment: Not that it matters, but 17.10 is _not_ an LTS release. They are even numbered (12, 14, 16, 18). And 17 is odd. ;-)

Comment: @PerlDuck Yeah, my bad....I usually stick to LTS but found the latest Non-LTS release handled my keyboard much better.