# Changing NVIDIA Drivers makes Ubuntu freeze on startup

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

I recently followed [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) by TensorFlow/Google on how to install all needed drivers/libraries in order to use Tensorflow with my GPU. That is a NVIDIA 1080Ti running on Ubuntu 18.04. In before, I was using the proprietary 430 (I think) driver, that gets automatically managed by Ubuntu.

After executing the following commands:

```
# Add NVIDIA package repositories
wget     https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys     https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1804_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1804_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update

# Install NVIDIA driver
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-driver-410
# Reboot. Check that GPUs are visible using the command: nvidia-smi
```

and rebooting, I am faced with the following situation:
Ubuntu always freezes on Startup, with no mouse movement/keyboard presses being accepted. Although my auto-login works (and the time in the top bar gets synchronised correctly), I am not able to do anything thereafter.

What I tried:

- I was able to get into recovery mode with networking. There, I installed the `nvidia-driver-430` package and auto-removed all older NVIDIA drivers. However, I am still faced with the exact same problem.
- Adding `nomodeset` into the kernel options does not resolve the problem either (Ubuntu still freezes on startup).

**My question:** How can I stop Ubuntu from freezing?

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) or [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver) because

- nomodeset didn‘t work
- I thus had to operate in recovery mode
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> didn‘t work

Comment: @EODCraftStaff I don‘t think that I could have found a solution from that post though

Comment: That is a very long all-encompassing Post isn't it?

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver) comes closer to answering my question. My problem is different though because I had to operate in recovery mode (as mentioned in my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by removing the NVIDIA drivers while in recovery mode.
Run the following commands in recovery mode:

```
# Enable networking and check for updates
sudo service network-manager start 
sudo apt update
# Reinstall Ubuntu-Desktop, install unity
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
# Remove NVIDIA
sudo apt remove --purge nvidia-driver-<YOUR NUMBER HERE>
# Reboot
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Afterwards you can use the standard Terminal and run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-<YOUR NUMBER HERE>` in order to reinstall your NVIDIA driver

Comment: Does FOSS Deserve Partial credit for this solution? https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/

Comment: @EODCraftStaff I saw that article, but it didn‘t work for me

Comment: I see, I did find a question and answer very similar to yours. Might want to take a look above.