# Black screen with x cursor on secondary monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

Nvidia X Server setup:

[image: Nvidia X Server setup]

- Using nvidia-driver-440
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- SecureBoot is disabled.

Only one monitor appears in display settings.

I've gone through [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver), but I'm getting the same result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the secondary and a third monitor recognized with the nouveau driver.

Comment: How? I'm having the same problem right now and Nouveau isn't changing anything :(