# Black screen with cursor

Tags: screen

I really need help..

I don’t understand much about Linux and computers yet. After I tried installing Nvidia drivers my laptop rebooted and now I am getting a black screen with only a cursor showing.

What do I need to do? Which info do you guys need to help. Please let me now which steps to follow because I don’t know much about Linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Also possibly: [Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver)